# Recursively list dependencies of a package in arch linux

Tags: printing, arch-linux, packages, dependencies, recursive

I'm trying to download driver of the AUR to install on a newly installed system (having no internet connection), however when I type

```
makepkg -s
```

It requires other packages to be installed. Being that this system has no internet I would like to download these packages (and all it's dependencies) from another PC having internet connection and later on install on the new system. I found a tutorial on the archlinux website about installing packages offline. Using

```
pacman -Sp <package_name> > /myPackages.list
```

Will create a list of all the packages that I specify in `package_name`. However I need all their dependencies too. So I want to know :

1. Is there a simple way to do this ?
2. Do I have to manually type in commands for every dependency package that is required ?
3. Can a shell script be written to accomplish this ? If yes, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

There is a program called [pactree](https://www.mankier.com/8/pactree) which is installed along with the [pacman](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/pacman/) package.
It's used to show the dependency tree for the specified package.

You can use it like this:

```
pactree -u <package_name>
```

However, unlike the `pacman -Sp <package_name>`, [pactree](https://www.mankier.com/8/pactree) only accepts one package name.

### One solution

There are several ways to work around this issue, but judging by your question, I don't have a feeling that you are familiar with shell scripts (sorry if I'm mistaken) so I will explain one solution in details:

```
echo "package_name1 package_name2 ..." | xargs -n 1 pactree -u | sort -u | xargs -n 1 pacman -Sp > /myPackages.list
```

`echo` - Shell builtin command: Prints the argument to the `stdout` (with appended new line).

`|` - Pipe: Redirects the `stdout` from the left command to the `stdin` of the right command.

`xargs` - External command: Takes `stdin` and appends it to the argument list of given command.
`-n 1` - `xargs` option: Execute the given command once for each argument from `stdin`.

`pactree` - External command: Show dependency tree for the given package.
`-u` - `pactree` option: Instead of a graph, print each dependency package in a separate line.

`sort` - External command: Sorts the text from the `stdin` and writes it to the `stdout`.
`-u` - `sort` option: Removes duplicates from sorted `stdin`.
(This is needed because some packages might have same dependencies.)

You are familiar with the rest of the line.

#### Note

`pacman -Sp` will report error if you give it the package from the AUR.

#### EDIT 17.09.2018

As pointed out by [JdeBP](https://superuser.com/users/38062/jdebp), `pactree` is in now in the [pacman-contrib](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/pacman-contrib/) package.

Comment: This answer is out of date.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469545/